# How do I exclude something from a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

Here is my code at the moment

```
percentagesOff = [5,10,15.....]

for percentage in percentagesOff:
     print("Percent off: ",percentage, end= " ")
```

and the output looks like this

```
Percent off: 5
Percent off: 10
Percent off: 15
```

and so on.

This is an example of what I want my code to look like. (have to use nested for loops as part of homework)

```
                     $10     $100    $1000
Percent off: 5%       x       x        x 
             10%      x       x        x
             15%      x       x        x 
             20%      x       x        x
```

My question is focusing on this part

```
Percent off: 5%
             10%
             15%
             20%
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to only print the `Percent off:` part once in my for loop.

Comment: Your code doesn't exactly match the output you pasted: the `end=" "` would make it so that everything is printed in one line.

Comment: sorry yes ignore the `end= " "`

Comment: I can ignore it well enough, but it is important that _you_ are very careful when copy&pasting code and output into your question.

Answer (score 3):

I really dislike teachers who tell students to accomplish something without having shown them the *right* tool for the job. I'm guessing you haven't yet been introduced to the `string.format()` method? Without which, lining up your columns will be an utter pain. You're trying to use a hammer when you need a screwdriver.

Anyway, regardless of that, I'd say that the right approach is to print a string of spaces the same length as 'Percent off:' when you don't want that string. So:

```
poff = 'Percent off: '
pad = ' '*len(poff)

p = poff
for percentage in percentagesOff:
     print(p ,percentage, end= " ")
     p = pad                   # for all subsequent trips around the loop
```

Better style would be to allow for the possibility that you might want `poff` output again (say) at the top of each page of output. So a better way to do the second code block is

```
for lineno, percentage in enumerate(percentagesOff):
     if lineno==0: # can replace later with are-we-at-the-top-of-a-page test?
         p = poff
     else
         p = pad
#    p = poff if lineno==0 else pad  # alternative shorter form
     print(p ,percentage, end= " ")
```

Comment: a relevant example for this problem is in the docs to `str.format()`. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-examples (the last one)

Comment: Thank you, very helpful, and no we don't get taught a whole lot. It's more, "have a go at this, but make sure you do it THIS way"

Answer (score 1):

You can just pull it out of the for loop, then it gets printed only once, or you could "remember" that you already printed it by setting some boolean variable to `True`(initialized at `False`) and then checking whether that variable is `True` or `False` before printing that part of the string.

Comment: That's one possibility, yeah!

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
percentagesOff = [5, 10, 15, 20]

print("Percent off:\t", percentagesOff[0], '%')
for percentage in percentagesOff[1:]:
    print("\t\t", percentage, "%")
```

Output

```
Percent off:     5 %
                 10 %
                 15 %
                 20 %
```

Comment: thank you, much easier than what I just attempted, using if, elif and else

Comment: No problem, delete the \n, my mistake.

Comment: i'd prefer `.format()` to meddling around with tabs and multiple arguments to `print()`. see the last example in the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-examples

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternate solution:

```
percentagesOff = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
print 'Percent off:    ', percentagesOff[0]            #use blanks instead of '\t'
for percentage in percentagesOff[1:]:
    print ' '*len('Percent off:    '), percentage
```

The last line, leaves one blank space for every character of the string ''Percent off:    '' and then start printing elements of array.

Basically, "len('something')" returns how many character does the string 'something' include. Then we muliply ' ' (which is one space) by that number.

Answer (score 0):

It is interesting excercise......
You can do something like this.

```
first = True

for p in pe:
    if first == True:
        print("percent off: ")
        first = False
        print(p)
    else:
        ....
        ....
```

But you would not normally do it this way.

Answer (score -1):

The fact is that python print add line break after your string to be printed. So,
Import `import sys` and, before your loop, use that:

```
sys.stdout.write('               $10     $100    $1000\n')
sys.stdout.write('Percent off:')
```

And now, you can start using print to write your table entries.

You can simply add a if statement with a boolean too.

Comment: I am not allowed to use fixed strings to print, I have to use nested for loops

Comment: It is weird and it makes it more difficult than it needs to be, but hey I guess thats what learning is about isn't it lol

Comment: there is no need to confuse a beginner with `sys.stdout.write` when `print()` is already capable of suppressing the newline (and the OP even has this in the question).

Comment: I didnt know it, how do you do that ?

In python 2.7 I mean, since Python3 is not really used in teaching for now.
Moreover, I think using __future__ is way more confusing than a simple buffer writing.

Comment: @ClovisPortron 1. the OP is clearly using Python3 2. in Python2, you can add a `,` after the print statement (more or less). 3. I would very much like to see your source for "Python3 is not really used in teaching"

Comment: @hop
1. Yeah, you're right, I was confused about the print() and print statement  

2. Thanks, I'll try that
  
3. I'm actually a student and, I all the structures I was in contact with, it was always about Python2.7 (In France, and Great Britain too). Moreover, the French "teaching minister" only speak about python2.7. After all, maybe it's only that my country is a bit late about IT stuffs ?

4. I was only trying to help, dont be so agressive mate :)